# Identify this seed pod

Tags: identification, flowers, seeds

We got a bouquet of cut flowers from someone attending a party we were hosting. It included this thing which I assume is a seed pod of some sorts.  It feels sort of like a baloon in that it is obviously hollow inside.  It is covered with small spines.  It has also lasted a really long time - longer than any of the flowers in the bouquet by far.

Can anyone tell me what it is?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I believe I answered my own question.  As luck would have it one of the pods split open the day I posted the question above.  The seeds inside were brown and had "parachutes" attached.  It looked a lot like some variety of asclepias (milkweed).  A little googling this morning and I think I found it...a milkweed native to Africa that goes by a variety of common names that refer to the balloon-like nature of the seed pods.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asclepias_physocarpa